# Function to replace a section of a regex match in PhpStorm

Tags: replace, ide, find, phpstorm

I'm translating French to English using a language file. In this file there are a lot of L'[word], c'[word], D'[word], La'[word].

The problem I am facing is that the single quote `'`, is also being used to define a string. From that point I can't simply replace all because of the differences.

Tried the obvious solutions like find and replace but that broke the file, googling regex find and replace, coworkers.

```
(\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\'\w*)
```

matches:

- `l'expédition`
- `s'est`
- `n'existe`

I want to replace it to:

- `l\'expédition`
- `s\'est`
- `n\'existe`

Comment: Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference

Comment: This is a good thing to check but it doesn't let me 'insert' new characters, only change them globally.

Comment: You make capture groups and then refer to them in replacement string using `$1`, `$2` etc notation -- capture part before `'`, then capture 2nd part; then the replacement would be something like `$1\\$2` (an overall idea). As you may notice from the screenshots on the Help page, replacement preview is available (so you can see how exactly it will be replaced)

Comment: Search for `(\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2})(\'\w*)`; replace by `$1\\$2` -- you just need to test it properly (e.g. `é` is not captured by `\w`) -- see screenshot: https://postimg.cc/7CFR0pcW

Comment: The replacement inserts "\" symbol between two matches (captured groups). Because it's a special symbol (used to escape other special symbols) it also needs escaping hence the "\\". `$1` refers to first capturing group, `$2` to the second (refer to regex docs as to what they are). Check this site: https://regex101.com/r/l5Wr9u/1